# vtables for derived, concrete, classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism, vtable, virtual-functions

If I have one base class and I derive 10 different concrete derived classes from it then will each and every concrete derived class have a different vtable?

Comment: What language/runtime/compiler etc.?

Comment: My guess is C++. It is the only popular language which has both virtual and non-virtual methods.

Comment: Why is this tagged as subjective?

Answer (score 4):

If the base class or all of the derived classes have any virtual functions, then yes, usually. Why is it important?

Two classes can only share a vtable if they have an indentical set of virtual functions.
So a derived class can only share a vtable with a base class if it doesn't override any virtual functions.

A derived class can't share a vtable with any other derived class unless they both don't override any functions of the same base class as - even if implemented in the same way - the member functions of one derived class are a different type from the member functions of a different derived class.

Comment: i was just confused that whether all the derived classes gonna use a single v table or they gonna have different

Comment: yes indeed every derived class is over riding the virtual functions of their own since the base class is purely abstract so are there gonna b seprate v tables???

Comment: They can only share a vtable if they have an indentical set of virtual functions. This means that a derived class can only share a vtable with a base class if it doesn't override any virtual functions.

Comment: Two classes can never share the vtable.  This table contains not only pointers to virtual members, but also the information needed by RTTI.

Comment: Note all C++ compilers agressively optimise vtables often by using thunks etc so I'd never 100% rely on a vtable being there as you'd expect

Comment: @AProgrammer: Usually true, yes. There's no requirment that RTTI has to be implemented as part of the vptr/vtbl mechanism, though. Of course, there's no language requirement to use vtables at all but it is the most common implementation strategy.

Comment: @zebrabox: I'm not sure how thunks in vtables would be an optimization, but yes, in general, compilers can do any 'magic' they like with vtables.

Comment: @Charles Bailey. Here's a PDF that explains thunk optimisation http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~urs/oocsb/papers/oopsla96.pdf. Though I will say that the optimisation is only really effective for multiple inheritance. Also 'thunk' in this context is bad term is it's more a wrapper function but the name thunk seems to have stuck

Comment: Theoretical question: Is there anything in the C++ specs that forces implementing virtual functions via vtables? I think it is the best method to implement them but in theory there could be C++ implementations that resolve virtual functions addresses in a very different way.

Comment: @rstevens: Not at all. By far the most trivial counterexample is inlining the vtable itself in every object, instead of inserting a vtable pointer. Saves you one level of indirection but is almost certain to increase object size.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether your derived classes override/declare any virtual methods.